# Rocksdb bloom filter stats showing zero values

Tags: rocksdb, rocksdb-java

I have configure rocksdb with prefix extractor and bloom filter. While writing data into the column family I getting the following logs

```
{"time_micros": 1709115199878830, "cf_name": "combined", "job": 4, "event": "table_file_creation", "file_number": 13, "file_size": 20115979, "file_checksum": "", "file_checksum_func_name": "Unknown", "smallest_seqno": 1153448, "largest_seqno": 1730120, "table_properties": {"data_size": 19304584, "index_size": 218347, "index_partitions": 0, "top_level_index_size": 0, "index_key_is_user_key": 1, "index_value_is_delta_encoded": 1, "filter_size": 720773, "raw_key_size": 25370180, "raw_average_key_size": 44, "raw_value_size": 29962236, "raw_average_value_size": 51, "num_data_blocks": 5045, "num_entries": 576595, "num_filter_entries": 576609, "num_deletions": 0, "num_merge_operands": 0, "num_range_deletions": 0, "format_version": 0, "fixed_key_len": 0, "filter_policy": "bloomfilter", "column_family_name": "combined", "column_family_id": 3, "comparator": "leveldb.BytewiseComparator", "user_defined_timestamps_persisted": 1, "merge_operator": "nullptr", "prefix_extractor_name": "rocksdb.FixedPrefix.23", "property_collectors": "[]", "compression": "LZ4", "compression_options": "window_bits=-14; level=32767; strategy=0; max_dict_bytes=0; zstd_max_train_bytes=0; enabled=0; max_dict_buffer_bytes=0; use_zstd_dict_trainer=1; ", "creation_time": 1709115196, "oldest_key_time": 1709115196, "file_creation_time": 1709115199, "slow_compression_estimated_data_size": 0, "fast_compression_estimated_data_size": 0, "db_id": "3bb22872-bd8a-43da-897a-3132fbbb2702", "db_session_id": "JJQLOTB4MYPSVP0VGDQD", "orig_file_number": 13, "seqno_to_time_mapping": "N/A"}}
```

which indicates that filter is configured, but once I run a load test, where I am doing a bunch of prefix seek(), In rocksdb stats the following metrics are always zero

```
rocksdb.bloom.filter.prefix.checked COUNT : 0
rocksdb.bloom.filter.prefix.useful COUNT : 0
rocksdb.bloom.filter.prefix.true.positive COUNT : 0
```

I am unable to understand if bloom filter is actually working.
using rocksdbjni version 8.8.1

Is my bloomfilter in rocksdb working properly, is some configuration wrong?